# Powershell: How to use Invoke-WmiMethod to Beep a Remote Computer?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0

I am trying to use the following code to make a beep on a remote computer through Powershell:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "[console]::beep(500,300)" -ComputerName "mycompname"
```

In addition I have used `[System.Media.SystemSounds]::Beep.Play()` in place of the console command.
It doesn't give any error codes and outputs this:

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
ProcessId        :
ReturnValue      : 9
PSComputerName   :

I am running this command with elevated Powershell and I am an admin on the network.  Using *Invoke-Command* **DOES NOT** work on my computer, so I am opting for Invoke-WmiMethod instead.  The following code **DOES** actually work, so I don't understand why the beep one won't:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "msg * 'hello'" -ComputerName "mycompname"
```

Final notes: I would like to be able to use Invoke-WmiMethod to do remote shutdown and taskkill, but those functions also do not work, only sending a message works.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `msg.exe` is an executable it can run, `[console]::beep()` is not, it's a .Net class method. The executable you need Win32_Process to start is powershell.exe with appropriate arguments to have the beep as a script/command for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

May be can you try this (modify username and password)

```
 $Username = 'labuser'
 $Password = 'labuser'
 $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
 $Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass


 Invoke-command –computername "mycompname" -credential $Cred –scriptblock {[console]::beep(500,300)}
```

Answer (score 0):

TessellatingHeckler was right.  I just needed to change the code so that the receiving computer knows that I am using powershell:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,300)" -ComputerName "mycompname"
```

This also works for everything else:

```
 Invoke-WmiMethod -Path Win32_Process -Name Create -ArgumentList "powershell.exe shutdown -s" -ComputerName "mycompname"
```

Thanks!